# TypeORM: How to apply generalization / specialization in typeORM?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, typeorm

I have two different types of users - let's say vendor and labour. They are non-overlapping and non-covering (i.e., some users may be neither vendor nor labour and a vendor can never be a labour).

The SQL representation would look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...)
CREATE TABLE vendors(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(id), ...)
CREATE TABLE labour(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(id), ...)
```

But what is a good way to represent this with TypeORM?

This is one possibility but it isn't a good design:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @OneToOne(type => Vendor, v => v.user, { nullable: true })
    vendor: Vendor;

    @OneToOne(type => Labour, l => l.user, { nullable: true })
    labour: Labour;
}

@Entity('vendors')
export class Vendor extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id: number;

    @OneToOne(type => User, u => u.vendor)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'id' })
    user: User;
}

...
```

Is there a better approach? Is it better to just leave out the reverse relations?

Comment: What are vendors and labours? How do you use these tables afterwards? How can they change in the future?

Comment: @zenbeni They’re just two different types of users. The vendor table will have more fields regarding their business, foreign keys to other tables like offices. Labour would have profile fields and foreign keys to other tables like ratings etc! I don’t imagine them changing a lot but as we add more functionality, they might start having foreign keys to other tables (like if we add a badge to each labour user).